# Can a facebook friend request be sent from my own app?

Tags: ios, facebook

I am creating an app and want to know if my app can send a Facebook friend request (say I know the other users id/name) or does Facebook not allow this?

Comment: I doubt Facebook would allow this.

Comment: I use bump and bump allows you to just bump your phone with someone else's (obviously after giving it the FB permission) to send a friend request through bump. So I am sure that it is possible, but am curious about the process. Can someone help me out here?

Comment: Check out this link: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14157784/can-we-invite-people-to-use-our-app-or-send-friend-request-from-the-app-via-face/16605625#16605625

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The short answer is "no."

The Facebook API does not allow you to programmatically send friend requests, but with some work, you may be able to use a WebView to load a Friend Request dialog via Javascript (For info on the request dialog, check https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/dialogs/requests/).