# Send friend request to fb user via app

Tags: ios, facebook, facebook-graph-api

Hi frnds I need to send friend request via app I cant find any solution for this..

```
NSMutableDictionary *params =
    [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
     @"FacebookId", @"id",
     nil];

    [FBWebDialogs presentDialogModallyWithSession:nil dialog:@"friends" parameters:params handler:nil];
```

Now I'm using this code but I got **"We're working on getting this fixed as soon as we can"**.

I refer those link but I cant catch what they telling.

1.[Can a facebook friend request be sent from my own app?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8360882/can-a-facebook-friend-request-be-sent-from-my-own-app)
2.https://developers.facebook.com/docs/games/requests/v1.0

Pls help me to fix this issue.

Comment: _“I refer those link but I cant catch what they telling”_ – what about a simple “That is not possible” do you have trouble understanding with …?

Answer (score 2):

You can't send friends requests using the API